# email confirmation using javascript and activator

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, express, confirmation

I need to set up email confirmation/verification for my Login & Registration feature. I found Activator on github, its suppose to be a simple way to handle user activation and password reset for your nodejs apps ([https://github.com/deitch/activator](http://github.com/deitch/activator)). I've read the docs but cannot get the simple example.js working at all. I don't understand this error.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundle
            ^
Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/Users/user/Desktop/activator-master/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:99:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/activator-master/example.js:139:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
1 Oct 12:16:29 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? "Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware."

Comment: Yes, I looked at this repository.. not sure how it helps ??

Comment: Well have you done what it says?

Comment: I've read the docs, and assume I have to change this line..

Comment: app.use(express.bodyParser()); But it's not clear what the syntax is suppose to look like. any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
npm install body-parser
```

Comment: Did you try to add a specific require for 'body-parser'?